# expl3 property lists and expansion

Tags: expl3

Trying to keep this simple. Given that the following, what is wrong with the commented out code (neither one works unfortunately), and what is an alternative way to do that? "That" being access a property list via a key which needs to be expanded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\tl_new:N \templist
\prop_new:N \tablestart
    \prop_put:Nnn \tablestart {u}{tablestart 1}
    \prop_put:Nnn \tablestart {u}{tablestart 2}
    \prop_put:Nnn \tablestart {u}{tablestart 3}
\tl_new:N \tablebody
\seq_new:N \entryuvw
    \seq_put_right:Nn \entryuvw {u}
    \seq_put_right:Nn \entryuvw {v}
    \seq_put_right:Nn \entryuvw {w}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \make_entry:n {
    \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 3 } {
        \tl_set:Nx \templist {\seq_item:Nn \entryuvw {##1}}
        \templist
        %\prop_get:NxN \tablestart {\tl_use:N \templist} \tablebody
        %\prop_get:NVN \tablestart \templist \tablebody
    }
    \tablebody
}

\make_entry:n {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

needs an output line
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:NnN { Nx }`.

Comment: I dont understand, what does that do exactly?

Comment: I meant that it wasn't defined. You need to generate `\prop_get:NxN` if it is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
\prop_get:NVN \tablestart \templist \tablebody
```

which is equivalent to

```
\prop_get:NnN \tablestart {<contents of \templist>} \tablebody
```

Your naming of variables is wrong, I'm afraid: please adhere to the `expl3` conventions in this regard.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_bob_templist_tl
\tl_new:N \l_bob_tablebody_tl
\prop_new:N \l_bob_tablestart_prop
\seq_new:N \l_bob_entryuvw_seq

\prop_put:Nnn \l_bob_tablestart_prop {u}{tablestart 1}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_bob_tablestart_prop {v}{tablestart 2}
\prop_put:Nnn \l_bob_tablestart_prop {w}{tablestart 3}

\seq_put_right:Nn \l_bob_entryuvw_seq {u}
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_bob_entryuvw_seq {v}
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_bob_entryuvw_seq {w}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \make_entry:
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 3 }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_bob_templist_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_bob_entryuvw_seq {##1}}
    \l_bob_templist_tl
    \prop_get:NVN \l_bob_tablestart_prop \l_bob_templist_tl \l_bob_tablebody_tl
    \l_bob_tablebody_tl
   }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeentry}{}{\make_entry:}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\makeentry

\end{document}
```

I've made the macro to print the contents of the two token list variables for checking that the result is what's expected.

[image]

Comment: Darn it I even tried that, but not until I had made this minimum working example, in which I made a typo in line 10,11, and 12, in which I accidentally assigned all three property values to the same key. Anyways thanks for the help egreg. As for the naming thing I am confused. When I first asked about this and did some research I was led to believe that the names didnt actually have an effect? Does adding the variable type and local/global actually change the way it works?